# Firebug issue: "Step Over" misbehaves with recursive functions

Tags: javascript, firefox, recursion, firebug

I've had a strange problem in Firebug. Actually, I googled for this and found something on the web.
[Issue 5176 on Firebug Project](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5176)

I don't want to describe the problem as it is exactly the same as described by this link. But... I didn't realise how to fix it. I don't know what does JSD stand for and if I need to update something.

I have up-to-date Debian system, thoung my browser is Iceweasel (Firefox) 17.0.10 and Firebug is 1.11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSD stands for JavaScript Debugger and means the API exposed by Firefox, which is used by Firebug to debug JavaScript within it's [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel). There's a new version of this API called JSD2, which the Firebug Working Group is [adapting](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421) for the next major version of Firebug.

Unfortunately there's no way to fix this on the user side, nor will it be fixed in the old JSD API, because Mozilla doesn't maintain it anymore.

Though as soon as the JSD2 is adapted by Firebug this bug will be gone.

Though note, when that version of Firebug is released in the next few months it will require at least Firefox/Iceweasel 29.0 or 30.0. So you'll need to update to the latest version of your browser then.

Comment: As I am using Debian I get all the updates for two years later, unfortunately. But in any case thank you a lot for making it clear, despite the fact that the problem could not be solved.

Comment: I don't use Debian, but it seems that you can also get [experimental releases for Iceweasel](http://packages.qa.debian.org/i/iceweasel.html) from debian.org. So you could also get the current version of Firebug then.